# Reset Testing Environment in Eclipse for plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing an eclipse plugin for custom resource markers. It has a custom view. Whenever I add a custom field to that view like Author Name, Date and Time, or Comment and launch the testing environment to see the added fields, it doesn't reflect the changes I made in the xml as well as the code of the plugin. Sometimes restarting the eclipse ide even doesn't help. And sometimes changes are reflected. Is there anyway of resetting the testing environment in eclipse so that new changes to the code can be seen? I am badly stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the 'Run > Run Configurations' entry for your Eclipse Application.

On the 'Arguments' tab make sure you have **-clean** in the 'Program Arguments' section.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I saw this note in the book given on the link below. They said they have reset the test environment. But there is no procedure for it.
https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=6Ob1ANNVcXcC&pg=PA627&lpg=PA627&dq=how+to+define+a+custom+marker+in+eclipse&source=bl&ots=jnExdLUnxB&sig=ZyRA8tQrDxT7lYuG4ciVywiWpzU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBmoVChMItMjps-qcyQIVyQSOCh0X8gZO#v=onepage&q=reset%20test&f=false